# Can't set UIImage to UIImageView from Url?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I can't understand why I can't set the uimageview from url from the example below:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/08/e9/14/mzi.lmcnwrii.60x60-50.jpg"]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

self.imgAlbum1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

it works fine by browsing the image, IBOutlet is ok, even setting uiimage from imagenamed doesn't work

I tried to recreate the contorl in the storyboard but nothing...

any tips are appreciated

Comment: Have you tried printing out `data` after that first call?

Comment: yes, nsdata is printing fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably `imgAlbum1` is an outlet to your existing image view.

Instead of that last line, which tries to create a new image view without displaying it anywhere, you probably want:

```
self.imgAlbum1.image = image;
```

Comment: not sure what is going on, I can't even set other controls pragmatically like uibutton titles. programming 17 hours straight not sure if I missed something obvious... I will try to create a new viewcontroller and try again..I tried that before by the way, didn't work either

Comment: I created a whole new project and now it is working fine, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If your `imgAlbum1` is an `IBOutlet`, you probably set it as a WEAK property.  If that is the case, the image will never show up.  In order to use **`alloc`**, your property would have to be a STRONG property.

Since you are probably using a WEAK outlet, try using `self.imgAlbum1` as the other poster suggested.  The reason this will work though, is because you're just updating the image, not the actual `imageView` object (weak properties, when you re-alloc will essentially destroy the object completely).

This is what I did which I tested and works just fine:

```
NSString *encodedString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"us/r30/Music/08/e9/14/mzi.lmcnwrii.60x60-50.jpg"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://a4.mzstatic.com/%@", encodedString]];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

UIImageView *imgAlbum1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[self.view addSubview:imgAlbum1];
```

So the questions for me are:

- Are you using a WEAK property for imgAlbum1 (ie: `@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet *imgAlbum1)`?  If so, don't set it to strong - rather, just use `self.imgAlbum1.image = image;`
- Have you ensured you have an internet connection with the device you are using?
- Is `imgAlbum1` an `IBOutlet` to a `UIImageView` ?  If so, is it hidden (or hidden by a layer)?
- Are you on the right view controller?

etc.

Otherwise, the code seems fine.